# jboss-cli without full jboss/EAP installation

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

For administering a JBoss 7 / EAP 6 installation, I'd like to provide a minimal package in which I only have the `jboss-cli.bat` script and all dependent modules/jar files. Maybe I am too stupid to use the correct terms for searching but I just cannot find a possibility to easily get all and only the needed modules for such a package.

Is there any way to get such a file or some way to get all dependencies for `jboss-cli` at once? I know about other, standalone remote-administration features, e.g. the maven jboss-as plugin, but for my current setup I would prefer a standalone `jboss-cli` installation.

Answer (score 2):

You could ask jboss-modules to give you list of dependencies for selected module.

for example this command

> java -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules -deptree org.jboss.as.cli

when run from JBOSS_HOME would give you whole dependency tree for cli (org.jbos.as.cli is entry module for cli)

To be fair I don't recall what was the version of jboss modules that got -deptree option, but for sure it works with jboss modules we bundle in WildFly.
If noting else you could just copy over jboss-modules.jar from wildfly distro to run this command.

Also you could give WildFly core distribution a try it is a 14mb distro of WildFly core functionality together with CLI and it should work for connection to older versions of AS7/WildFly